# move_uploaded via a variable path

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, filepath

I'm trying to move uploaded files to nested folders with part of the path provided by a variable loaded from a form. As long as the variable contains just one folder, it works. It works if I load each folder into a separate variable too:

```
$one = "one" ;
$more = "more" ;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/$one/$more/$fileName");
```

I want the nested folders in one variable but it never works.

```
$thepath = $_POST["locate"]; //should be "one/more"
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/$thepath/$fileName");
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the separators but I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there (a blank space), change:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/$the path/$fileName");
```

to:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/$thepath/$fileName");
```

Comment: Thanks, the typo was in my post here though and not in the code that's failing me.